# Execute stage when shell command returns empty string

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline that executes a series of steps only if a shell command has returned an empty string.
Here is the whole pipeline, with the relevant section being stage "Start container":

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'maven:3-alpine'
      args '-v m2:/root/.m2'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn verify -DskipTests'
        archiveArtifacts(artifacts: 'target/*.war', fingerprint: true, onlyIfSuccessful: true)
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      post {
        always {
          junit 'target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'

        }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'mvn test'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy [dev]') {
      environment {
        CONTAINER = 'containerName'
        STARTUP_LOG = 'INFO: Server startup'
      }
      stages {
        stage('Install docker') {
          steps  {
            sh 'apk update && apk add docker'
          }
        }
        stage('Start container') {
          when {
            expression {
              sh '''if [ -z $(docker ps -f name=$CONTAINER -q) ]; then true; else false; fi'''
            }
          }
          steps {
            sh '''docker start $CONTAINER'''
            sh '''(docker logs -f --tail 10 $CONTAINER 2>&1 &) | grep -q "$STARTUP_LOG"'''
          }
        }
        stage('Deploy WAR') {
          steps {
            echo 'deploy war file'
            echo 'smoke test'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Acceptance') {
      steps {
        echo 'deploy stubs'
        echo 'run cucumber tests'
        echo 'publish report'
      }
    }
    stage('Release') {
      when {
        expression {
          env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
        }

      }
      steps {
        echo 'releasing'
        echo 'time to deploy to UAT'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a red flag during the execution of the when expression:

> ```
> [test_master-YKUBYJHFWV5SAO5BKANKYXEX6RUGQUBB2GGZLHYPHNUKZELZPATQ] Running shell script
>
> + docker ps -f name=containerName -q
> + [ -z c504c975f632 ]
> + false
> script returned exit code 1
> ```

I thought if the expression returned a false or a null then the associated stage was not going to be executed, but apparently, my understanding is wrong...

Any advice on how this can be achieved? Possibly without recurring to some magic goo :-D

### UPDATE

I have managed to fix the build error by adding the parameter `returnStatus:true` to the `sh` command, but it still doesn't prevent the execution of the step.

I've replaced the "Start container" stage now looks like this:

```
    stage('Start container') {
      when {
        expression {
          sh script: '''if [ -z $(docker ps -f name=$CONTAINER -q) ]; then true; else false; fi''', returnStatus: true
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh '''docker start $CONTAINER'''
        sh '''(docker logs -f --tail 10 $CONTAINER 2>&1 &) | grep -q "$STARTUP_LOG"'''
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `expression` block is actually equivalent to a pipeline `script` block, as such it can only contain groovy scripts, so the above stage should be changed to

```
    stage('Start container') {
      when {
        expression {
          def containerId = sh(script: 'docker ps -f name=$CONTAINER -q', returnStdout: true)
          return containerId.trim() == ""
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh "docker start $CONTAINER"
        sh '''(docker logs -f --tail 10 $CONTAINER 2>&1 &) | grep -q "$STARTUP_LOG"'''
      }
    }
```

Careful reading the documentation usually helps...